# Android N Inline reply issue for priority message

Tags: android, notifications, whatsapp

I observed one issue while doing inline reply for priority messages. If you reply directly when your notification is being displayed on other app or on home screen. The reply works perfectly but it does not remove the notification from status bar and notification panel.

And the same issue is with WhatsApp as well.

I have gone through [Google Developer Doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) and [Android Developer Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/06/notifications-in-android-n.html) but could not figure out the resolution.

Here are the testing videos :

- [WhatsApp Notification Testing](http://sendvid.com/se8sn97r//)
- [My App Link](http://sendvid.com/jhukd0w0)

**Notification Code**

```
 /**
 * Create chat message reply ui
 *
 * @param singleUserMessage
 * @param context
 * @param channelId
 * @param RecipientUserId
 * @param builder
 */
private void setDirectChatReply(boolean singleUserMessage, Context context, String channelId, String RecipientUserId, NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
    if (singleUserMessage && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        // Key for the string that's delivered in the action's intent.
        RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(Constants.GCM.DIRECT_REPLY_KEY)
                .setLabel(getString(R.string.direct_reply_notif_label))
                .build();
        // Create the reply action and add the remote input.
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(context, ReplyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        broadcastIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(Constants.Conversations.CHANNEL_ID, channelId);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(Constants.Conversations.RECIPIENT_USER_ID, RecipientUserId);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra(Constants.Conversations.CHAT_USER_ID, mDesidimeSharedPreferences.getMyChatUserId());
        PendingIntent replyIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Constants.NotificationValues.CHAT_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Action action = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_send,
                getString(R.string.notif_action_reply), replyIntent).addRemoteInput(remoteInput).build();
        builder.addAction(action);
    }
}
```

**DirectReply class to handle inline replies**

```
    public class ReplyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements MessageSenderTask.ChatMessageProcessor {
    private static final String TAG = "ReplyBroadcastReceiver";
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
        // Hit Analytics
        DesidimeSharedPreferences sharedPreferences = new DesidimeSharedPreferences(context);
        Bundle remoteInput = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent);
        if (remoteInput != null) {
            String reply = remoteInput.getString(Constants.GCM.DIRECT_REPLY_KEY);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(reply)) {
                Bundle dataBundle = intent.getExtras();
                dataBundle.putString(Constants.Conversations.MESSAGE_KEY, reply);
                dataBundle.putString(Constants.Conversations.MESSAGE_TYPE, Constants.Conversations.MESSGE_TYPE_CHAT);
                MessageSenderTask messageSenderTask = new MessageSenderTask(context, this);
                messageSenderTask.setMessageData(dataBundle, sharedPreferences.getUserId());
                messageSenderTask.execute();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageProcessed(Bundle data) {
        if (data != null) {
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.cancel(Constants.NotificationValues.CHAT_NOTIFICATION_ID);
            updateUnreadConversationStatus(data.getString(Constants.Conversations.RECIPIENT_USER_ID));
        }


    }

    /**
     * Locally manage read/unread conversation for Recent user list
     * @param recipientId
     */
    private void updateUnreadConversationStatus(String recipientId) {
        try {
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(recipientId)) {
                ChatManager chatManager = new ChatManager(DBTables.Conversations.TABLE_RECENT_USER_LIST, mContext);
                chatManager.updateConversationUnreadStatus(recipientId);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Crashlytics.log(Log.DEBUG, TAG, "updateUnreadConversationStatus recipientId : "+recipientId);
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageProcessedFailed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageProcessedFailed");
    }
}
```

*Here on onMessageProcessed , I am removing the notification from notification panel.*